# What are handcuffs for?

Tags: jagged-alliance-2

I'm playing on the jagged alliance 2 [1.13 fanpatch/mod](http://ja2v113.pbworks.com/w/page/4218339/FrontPage). And some mercs have handcuffs, does anybody know what they are for? They are not in the base game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See bear pit](http://thepit.ja-galaxy-forum.com/index.php?t=msg&goto=312705&&srch=pacifist%20handcuff#msg_312705)

You use them on enemies to get them to surrender when you have the upper hand on them - unlike using "lips" on the enemy to demand surrender from all of them, this only deals with the one, which means it's easier, especially if he's already wounded, knocked out or such.

Probably shouldn't, but you can steal [STRG+click-on-enemy] the handcuffs back before the battle is over and he'll stay "captured".

Then when the battle is over you can let them go free (some chance that they'll go back to the army, some chance they'll be sick of the war and stop) -- or if you own a town with a prison you can send them there. You should have militia and/or mercs there to defend the prison/keep prisoners in, else they'll "riot" and turn into hostiles there. Not so pleasant...

Why do that? Because you can have mercs "talk" with them (by working in the prison facility). This has a chance of getting you a randsom for letting them free, info about enemy movement or sometimes they join you.